# Serialize :new in trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, trigger, plsql

I have a trigger that needs to create an Oracle Advanced queue message. The payload of that message should contain the new record that was created, that is accessible via :new.

What I am looking for is a way to transform the :new object into raw or a custom data type that can be set as the payload of the queue message, in a generic way.

At the moment I'm trying to convert :new to anydata and set that as the payload data type.

Comment: are you seeking for the code to convert :new data to other data types explicitly? i mean trying to convert to varchar2, number etc regardless of the type of :new data.

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to get the full :new converted to anydata, or raw, or whatever enables me to get its data into the queue's payload. I am trying to avoid accessing properties of :new, to have a generic solution.

Comment: Possible duplicates [In an Oracle trigger, can I assign new and old to a rowtype variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610295/in-an-oracle-trigger-can-i-assign-new-and-old-to-a-rowtype-variable#comment29109933_19610295), [Can I copy :OLD and :NEW pseudo-records in/to an Oracle stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337325/can-i-copy-old-and-new-pseudo-records-in-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure) and [Oracle PL/SQL: Forwarding whole row to procedure from a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423466/oracle-pl-sql-forwarding-whole-row-to-procedure-from-a-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented what you are trying to do this way:  the transformation to a user defined object happens in a packaged procedure that is called by triggers.

```
---all comments and debugging removed to keep it simple----    
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER when_close_ini
   AFTER UPDATE OF end_date
   ON YOUR_TABLE
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN
   IF :NEW.end_date IS NULL AND :OLD.end_date IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      my_schema.queue_util.add_file_to_queue ('REOPEN', :NEW.ID, NULL);

   END IF;

END when_close_ini;

----------------an excerpt from the package with debugging removed----
 PROCEDURE add_file_to_queue   (action_in      IN VARCHAR2,
                                d_case_id_in   IN NUMBER,
                                d_other_in     IN VARCHAR2 := NULL)
   IS

      queue_options        SYS.DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
      message_properties   SYS.DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
      message_id           RAW (16);
      my_message           MY_SCHEMA.file_action;
      err_text             VARCHAR2 (2000);
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   BEGIN

      my_message := my_schema.file_action (action_in, d_case_id_in, d_other_in);
      DBMS_AQ.enqueue (queue_name           => 'MY_SCHEMA.MY_QUEUE',
                       enqueue_options      => queue_options,
                       message_properties   => message_properties,
                       payload              => my_message,
                       msgid                => message_id);
     COMMIT;
   END add_file_to_queue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this with the PL/SQL project manager years ago, and was told that it is not possible. You can't address the :NEW or :OLD columns as a record and convert them to anything. You can create a temporary table that is either identical to the table that you are writing the trigger for or generic, i.e. table_name, column_name, column_type, clob. You would then insert the :NEW or :OLD values into the temporary table and you can access those values with an after statement trigger. Then you can read the data in an after statement trigger.